# 11.04 will not run on Aspire One

Tags: 11.04, installation, aspire-one

I'm trying to install 11.04 but after a while it will start showing a stream of random characters on screen, then get stuck and finally open BusyBox. If I type exit there I come up with a "Panic occurred, switching back to text console" error and from there the loading won't progress. What's wrong?

Comment: How are you installing 11.04? have you tried another version or alternative? (64/32?) i'm sorry, but we need to know more to help you better.

Comment: I don't know whether this netbook has a 64-bit processor or not, but it's an Intel Atom N450 and I think it might support 64-bit. The version I've downloaded is ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386

Comment: did you install it with a live-cd CD or a USB? Have you tried using another install of the version (reinstall the system on a new/same usb/cd? )

Comment: I'm doing it through USB, and no I haven't tried on another system because currently none of the systems in my house support booting from USB, and the Aspire One has no CD reader.

Comment: try and reinstall the Ubuntu version you downloaded, something might have gone wrong. Btw have you Google your computer to see if it's supported at all?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne
Does this help?

Comment: It says:
Aspire One 532h (Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10)
Does this mean that this computer won't support 11.04?

Comment: It might not support 11.04, but try with 10.04 or 10.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your model isn't supported in the [official list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne) then I suggest you try an older version that is supported like 10.10 or 10.04 LTS.

it would make it easier to help you more if we knew the exact model.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne

I would guess from your tips that your model is [Aspire One 532h](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne/532h).

Comment: My experience (and logic) says that hardware support in older versions of Ubuntu should be WORSE then in newer ones - apart from maybe additional requirements such as 3D graphics for Unity. I mean, development process consists of adding features and fixing bugs, not removing features and adding bugs :) So, in this light, I would try to install 11.10 to see if it works, not some old version.

Comment: well if LTS or 10.10 is supported then I would start there and if i really would want to. Then I would upgrade to 11.04 or 11.10. But my tip wait a couple of weeks after 11.10 is released so you don't get a million bugs. 

I know it feels like something is wrong when you have to use an old version of Linux because of compatibility issues. And 10.04 hasn't that much support, for like laptops.

Answer (score 0):

We need a little more info, How far into the "install" are you getting? Can you boot to the LiveCD version?

As for an answer, I find when the installer fails, I found using the **[alternate installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download)** will do the job.

[http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#alternate)
Click the [**location near you**](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download) link, navigate to the version you want to install and select the *alternate* one, with the correct architecture.

Comment: No, I cannot boot into the live CD. I'll try the alternate version.